# Prove that this entire function $f$ is constant

Tags: complex-analysis

I need help for this problem:

If $f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ is entire function such that $f(z+1)=f(z)$ and $|f(z)|<e^{|z|}$, $\forall z\in\mathbb{C}$, prove that $f$ is constant function.

[Hint: Look function $g(z)=\frac{f(z)-f(0)}{\sin \pi z}$]

Comment: What can you say about $g(z)$? (a) when $z$ is near an integer, and (b) when $z$ is large and imaginary?

Comment: I know that $g(z+2)=g(z)$, $\forall z\in\mathbb{C}$ but i don't know how to limit $|g|$.a) when $z$ is near an integer, then $\lim g(z)=\infty$. I tried with $\sin(\pi z)=\frac{e^{i\pi z}+e^{-i\pi z}}{2i}$, but how i can use fact that $|f(z)|<e^{|z|}$?

Comment: Look for a _lower bound_ for $|\sin(x+iy)|$ as a function of $y$.

Comment: You think a lower bound for $|\sin(\pi(x+iy))|$? how ?

Comment: Yes, thanks. I didn't see that. Thaks to all for help

Comment: @Pascal: Right, the $\pi$ factor makes it even better. Try trigonometric addition formulas, and remember that $\cosh t > |\sinh t| \ge \frac{e^{|t|}-1}2 $

Comment: @HenningMakholm I didn't know that inequality, thanks :)